# JQuery How to get number of this div

Tags: html, jquery

I have a few divs:

```
<div class="somediv">text</div>
<div class="somediv">text</div>
<div class="somediv">text</div>
<div class="somediv">text</div>
```

And when I click on for example the third div, I want to return the number 3.

I have tried something like this but it didn't work:

```
console.log($("this").index);
```

Comment: jQuery has an index function so you call it like `index()`. Post a [mcve] please including your click event handler

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotation marks - it should be `console.log($(this).index());`. Note: the index starts with 0.

**Working example**:

```js
$('.somediv').on('click', function() {
    console.log($(this).index());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
    <div class="somediv">text</div>
    <div class="somediv">text</div>
    <div class="somediv">text</div>
    <div class="somediv">text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh okay. I thought I had tried this and it had said "index is not a function", now I tried it again and it worked... thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

`var index = $(".somediv").index(this);`